# HTMX: Passing a function to `hx-on` for reading the event

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, htmx

I must be missing the absolute obvious here:

Using htmx I am trying to send a get request and configure it in javascript before sending it. HTMX provides `hx-get`, `hx-on` and the `configRequest` event for basically exactly that.

However I seem to be missing a big obvious button since I could not get `hx-on` to perform a function or lambda I give it, only immediate JS works which (by it's nature) cannot accept arguments and therefor cannot access the event.

In short: What am I missing to get the following to work as expected?

```html
<button hx-get="/api/things"
        hx-on:config-request="event => console.log(' ', event)"
        hx-target="#target"
>Click Me!</button>
<p id="target">...</p>
```

- `hx-on:config-request="console.log('This will work ')"` will work but obviously cannot engage with the event.
- `hx-on:config-request="() => console.log('This won't work ')"` won't work
- `hx-on:config-request="console.log"` won't work as well
- `hx-on:config-request="someOtherKnownMethod"` won't work as well

I'm confused.

Thanks for your time. Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event keyword is accessible directly, so you don't need to use lambda function. Also you're missing "::" which is a shorter way of accessing htmx events.

Smth like this should work (make sure you have the latest htmx js lib version):

```
hx-on::config-request="console.log(' ', event)"
```